# What was the inspiration for the trampoline storyline in "Aerodynamics of Gender"?

Tags: reference, community

In Community season 2, episode 7, *Aerodynamics of Gender*, Troy discovers a place of peace with a magical trampoline. What movie/television show inspired this storyline?

Comment: Do you have a special reason to believe it was inspired by something? While Community sometimes does parodies of other movies/shows, I believe that most storylines are original.

Comment: @atticae I have a reason to believe it was inspired by something.

Comment: @atticae I just kept thinking that I'd seen that story before.  Especially about the two rules.

Answer (score 12):

It was inspired by [*The Secret Garden*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Secret_Garden).  It's a book I'm not familiar with, but [The Onion's AV Club says](http://www.avclub.com/articles/aerodynamics-of-gender,47075/):

> This trampoline storyline was like something out of *Simpsons*, almost directly. (That show also had a famous trampoline B-story.) However, *Community* makes its own story out of this basic premise by weaving together the idea of trampolines being hideously unsafe with **an elaborate parody of *The Secret Garden*** (complete with lush imagery out of the final season of *Lost*) and the end of every story where people discover paradise but then ruin it by ... leading other people to it.

<sub>emphasis mine</sub>

Reading over the Wikipedia summary of *The Secret Garden*, there are some obvious parallels.  The servants who introduce the protagonist to the garden, parallels the janitor in the *Community* episode.  Both works share the lush greenery, and the gardens in both share magical properties.

Answer (score 0):

the opening scene when Troy first goes to retrieve the basketball reminded me of Six Feet Under- the musicals cues (which after this first time, are used throughout the series) are very much in the foreground & super similar to six feet under's - the lighting is kind of hyper-soft & supernatural like SFU used to do in dream sequences & then there's that flash to white heading in to the title sequence

Not sure if it's a direct nod, or if the show's just being it's style-jumping self.